# How can I bind a MacBook Pro to another Apple ID account?

Tags: macos, apple-id

I've created a new account for my new MacBook, and want to join it with the old account.

I'll probably reset and then input the correct account ID.

Answer (score 2):

No need to start over from scratch. Just go to each part of the system where your Apple ID is used, log out of your new account, and log into your old account. Here's a starter list:

- iCloud panel in System Preferences.
- (Mac) App Store app.
- iTunes.
- iMessage/iChat.